# Pandas sort_index only the given timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing

I have a pandas series object consists of a datetime_index and some values, looks like following:

```
df
2020-01-01 00:00:00    39.6
2020-01-01 00:15:00    35.6
2020-01-01 00:30:00    35.6
2020-01-01 00:45:00    39.2
2020-01-01 01:00:00    56.7
...
2020-12-31 23:45:00    56.3
```

I am adding some values to this `df` with `.append()`. Since it is not sorted then I sort its index via `.sort_index()`. However what I would like to achieve is that I want to sort only for given day.

So for example I add some values to day `2020-01-01`, and since the added values will be after the end of the day `2020-01-01` I just need to sort the first day of the year. **NOT ALL THE DF.**

Here is an example, NaN value is added with `.append()`:

```
df
2020-01-01 00:00:00    39.6
2020-01-01 00:15:00    35.6
...
2020-01-01 23:45:00    34.3
2020-01-01 15:00:00    NaN
...
2020-12-31 23:45:00    56.3
```

Now I cannot `df.sort_index()`, because it breaks other days. That is why I just want to apply `.sort_index()` to the day `2020-01-01`. How do I do that?

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR AND DOES NOT WORK:**

```
df.loc['2020-01-01'] = df.loc['2020-01-01'].sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows for `2020-01-01` days, sorting and join back with not matched rows:

```
mask = df.index.normalize() == '2020-01-01'

df = pd.concat([df[mask].sort_index(), df[~mask]])
print (df)
2020-01-01 00:00:00    39.6
2020-01-01 00:15:00    35.6
2020-01-01 15:00:00     NaN
2020-01-01 23:45:00    34.3
2020-12-31 23:45:00    56.3
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Another idea:

```
df1 = df['2020-01-01'].sort_index()
df = pd.concat([df1, df.drop(df1.index)])
```

Comment: First one works, I can try also the second one. Can I ask you what does `~` before `mask` do? @jezrael thank you!!!

Comment: @oakca - It change `[False, True, True]` to `[True, False, False]`, working like `mask == False`

Comment: both of them works. So `~` is like an inverter, however I am not sure what is `[False, True, True]` stands for. Anyway

Comment: @oakca - I want explain like working inverting mask ;)